# How to store result of any redis command in a kay and how to store table data in redis structures?

Tags: redis

hi all I am new to redis and i want to use redis in our application for frequent database inserts/updates and deletes.

i have a table like this in postgres.

```
  testtbl                                                   

 unixtime   |   code    | flag1 |count1     |   count2  |   flag2
_________________________________________________________________
1353475056  |   1234    |  A    |60         |   8955    |     N   
1353475060  |   5248    |  B    |131        |   22500   |     F   
1353475056  |   7267    |  C    |36         |   10130   |     X   
1353475056  |   1908    |  B    |0          |       0   |     N   
1353475060  |   9290    |  E    |90         |   11905   |     X   
1353475056  |   6123    |  F    |1          |   702     |     F   
1353475060  |   4145    |  G    |117        |   47920   |     X   
1353475099  |   7000    |  L    |43         |   21720   |     F   
1353475099  |   3256    |  D    |40         |   3915    |     N
```

I tried to store these records using redis hashes as follows

```
hmset testtbl:1 unixtime 1353475056 code 1234 flag1 A count1  60 count2  8955 flag2 N
hmset testtbl:2 unixtime 1353475060 code 5248 flag1 B count1 131 count2 22500 flag2 F
hmset testtbl:3 unixtime 1353475056 code 7267 flag1 C count1  36 count2 10130 flag2 X
hmset testtbl:4 unixtime 1353475056 code 1908 flag1 B count1   0 count2     0 flag2 N
hmset testtbl:5 unixtime 1353475060 code 9290 flag1 E count1  90 count2 11905 flag2 X
hmset testtbl:6 unixtime 1353475056 code 6123 flag1 F count1   1 count2   702 flag2 F
hmset testtbl:7 unixtime 1353475060 code 4145 flag1 G count1 117 count2 47920 flag2 X
hmset testtbl:8 unixtime 1353475099 code 7000 flag1 L count1  43 count2 21720 flag2 F
hmset testtbl:9 unixtime 1353475099 code 3256 flag1 D count1  40 count2  3915 flag2 N
```

To get any record first I need to find key to that record, and 
then using that key perticular record need to be fetched like this

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall testtbl:3
 1) "unixtime"
 2) "1353475056"
 3) "code"
 4) "7267"
 5) "flag1"
 6) "C"
 7) "count1"
 8) "36"
 9) "count2"
10) "10130"
11) "flag2"
12) "X"
```

now questions are
1) how can I assign value of any key to another key or store result of any command in a kay ?
eg. if i want to store result of "TIME" command in redis to key testtbl: unixtime in this case
2) is there any other efficient way to store this data ?
3) how can I get all the records whose unixtime = 1353475056 or  flag2 = "N"
4) Is there any bulk get utility in redis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can only implement it in the client side.

2, 3) It's depends on the scenario. For the third question, you can use a sorted set to store the unixtime:

```
ZADD testtbl.unixtime 1353475056 testtbl:1 1353475060 testtbl:2 1353475056 testtbl:3 ...
```

To get all the records whose unixtime = 1353475056:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE testtbl.unixtime 1353475056 1353475056
1) "testtbl:1"
2) "testtbl:3"
```

Use a set to store flag2:

```
SADD testtbl.flag2:N testtbl:1 testtbl:4 testtbl:9
```

To get all the records whose flag2 = "N"

```
SMEMBERS testtbl.flag2:N
1) "testtbl:1"
2) "testtbl:4"
3) "testtbl:9"
```